# What is Starbound and is it only on PC, or on console and PC?

Tags: starbound

I've heard about this game in many groups on social media and I've heard that it's really fun to play. Can anyone tell me what it is? I've been wondering this for a long time and I finally broke and wanted to ask the question.

Comment: Your best bet would be to watch a few gameplay videos and [visit the Starbound website](http://playstarbound.com/)

Comment: The reason you didn't get a better answer is because all the information you seem to want to know about Starbound can be found by just Googling "starbound".  It even shows the supported platforms right there on the search page.

Comment: If you don't want to keep this question around then you can simply delete it - there's no need for editing it (which will only make the problem worse)

Comment: how do I delete it then?

Comment: There should be a "delete" link on the left hand side just below the list of tags

Comment: it doesnt show it

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. As long as it exists, it needs to actually *be* a question.

Comment: "delete" should be between "edit" and "flag". You can't delete your question if it has an upvoted answer, but the only answer here hasn't been voted on yet, so you should still be able to delete your question.

Comment: I started a Meta [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10917/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-ask-you-to-describe-a-game) about whether or not this type of question should be closed.

Answer (score 5):

Starbound is in development on the consoles (both XBone and PS4), but is currently only out (in a beta state) on the PC.

It is a multiplayer exploration/crafting/building game in the vein of Terraria or Minecraft. The universe is randomly generated and you can explore multiple planets, kill the alien life there, and build your own buildings.

[image: This is an outpost.]

*The above image depicts an [outpost](http://starbounder.org/Outpost), which can be accessed after repairing the engines in the initial stages of progression via warp gates located in the planetary system screen in the navigation screen.*

As you travel between and explore planets, you can gain crafting materials and gain new schematics to make yourself more powerful and to unlock more sectors of the galaxy.

Mostly, it's about running around and building cool stuff while trying not to die.